# Quiero crear un archivo zip pero GitHub Actions me tira un error cuando hago push

Tags: c#

Puede ser que no tenga nada que ver con crear un archivo `.zip` con `GitHub Actions`, pero el proyecto está alojado en Linux y para las actualizaciones usamos `GitHub Actions` para probar los cambios.

Resulta que tengo una galería de imágenes que se carga dinámicamente. Las imágenes están alojadas en un servidor, y las rutas de ellas guardadas en la base de datos. Yo recorro la base de datos con una consulta y las cargo en dicha galería.

Ahora, estoy intentando crear un botón para poder descargar todas las imágenes, "Descargar Todas las imagenes", y para ello estoy utilizando el paquete `DotNetZip`.

Html:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("DescargarImagenes", "Home", new { pedido = ViewBag.pedido}, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Descargar Todas las Imagenes" type="submit"/>
    </div>
}
```

Back:

```
public FileResult DescargarImagenes(string pedido)
        {
            string consulta;
            List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos;

            try
            {
                listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
                consulta = "SELECT DISTINCT e.Path from Pedido p INNER JOIN Entrega e ON p.Entrega = e.Entrega WHERE p.Pedido = '" + ViewBag.pedido + "'";
                listaPedidos = SelectConexionMySql(consulta);

                using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    foreach (var lista in listaPedidos)
                    {
                        var archivo_nombre = lista.getPathImagen();
                        var archivo_arregloBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(lista.getPathImagen());
                        zip.AddEntry(archivo_nombre, archivo_arregloBytes);
                    }

                    var nombreZip = "ImagenesPedido" + ViewBag.pedido;

                    using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        zip.Save(output);
                        return File(output.ToArray(), "application/zip", nombreZip);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

En Visual Studio no hay ningun error en la consola, todo debería funcionar. Cuando realizo un `git push`, la consola de `Github Actions` me tira este error y cancela el push:

> The type or namespace name 'Ionic' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

`Ionic` es el nombre del namespace que estoy utilizando para poder usar `ZipFile`:

```
using Ionic.Zip;
```

Queria saber qué puede estar pasando que el `Github` me está rechazando el `push`

Comment: Por favor resiva el siguiente (link)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok]